# PyInstaller: How to suppress error messages

Tags: python, pyinstaller

PyInstaller 3.6 | Python 2.7

I'm trying to suppress an error message box that appears every now and then when running my script. I know it would be better practice to figure out why the error is being thrown in the first place but given my circumstances, suppressing the error message is all I currently need.

The command I use to create my executable:

```
pyinstaller --onefile ScreenGrab.py --noconsole
```

I've also heard that using "--onefile" and "--noconsole" sometimes causes issues so in some cases I've also used the command:

```
pyinstaller --onefile ScreenGrab.pyw
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Screenshot of the error message:

[image]

Comment: please add some screenshots of the error box.

Comment: no problem good sir, added a screenshot to the end of my post

Comment: that is a error with pyinstaller. what are the name of libraries used in your project. and also provide some part of code that uses compiled c extension libraries.

Comment: and yeah no way of suppressing error message with pyinstaller. also run the script from command prompt without recompiling and send the output of command prompt

Comment: i could be wrong but i don't think i'm using any c extension libraries. the libraries currently used in this script include json, httplib, os, mimetypes, time, urlparse, urllib, ConfigParser, sys, pyautogui, socket, datetime, traceback, and subprocess.

Comment: i have this running as a scheduled task so it's not the end of the world if it fails once. I just don't want to have to actually click out of that error message since this script will be used on public displays. according to my logs, when it fails, my script doesn't even begin executing so my guess is it has something to do with the bootloader

Comment: I would suggest you to try the answer by @Deneb and share output screenshot

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the `--noconsole` flag during compilation, if you launch the output binary from a terminal (usually sitting in the `dist` folder), you will see the actual error inside the terminal window.

But if you want a more elegant way of handling exceptions, you can use a hook:

```
import sys
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox
import traceback


def excepthook(*exc_info):
    tb = "".join(traceback.format_exception(*exc_info))
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()  # Hides the root window.
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo(title="Error", message=tb)


sys.excepthook = excepthook  # Attach the hook.

# Cause the exception:
error = 1 + "1"
```

Now you get an actual error dialog, which you can use to debug your application.

A third alternative would be to use the `logging` module and log the errors to a file.

[image: error dialog]